# Javascript returning "undefined" when it knows what the string is

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've created a function that loops through one array, using each value (`item`) to check whether a different value (`clicked_item`) exists in an array called `item`.

This works great. In the log statement, it correctly identifies the parent (`item`) and the type (`string`). Output in console: `FOUND PARENT FOR: pinot-noir-gifts IT IS ITEM: red_wine_gifts TYPE: string`

However `return item` returns undefined when it should return `red_wine_gifts`. The result is that `clicked_item_parent` is undefined.

Why would the script be able to log a value but the function returns it as undefined?

```
function find_parent(clicked_item)
{
    filter_have_children.forEach( function(item){
        var look_here = filter_children[item];
        if ( look_here.indexOf(clicked_item) != "-1" ) 
        {
            console.log("FOUND PARENT FOR: "+clicked_item+" IT IS ITEM: "+item+" TYPE: "+typeof item);
            return item;
        }
    });
}

var clicked_item_parent = find_parent(clicked_item);

if ( typeof clicked_item_parent !== "undefined" )
{
    // Do some things
} 
else console.log("parent was undefined");
```

Comment: There is no `return` statement in `find_parent`, so the function always produces the default `undefined`. The `return` statement you have is inside the `.forEach()` callback, however that doesn't affect the outer function. Moreover, `.forEach()` doesn't return anything. You should use a normal loop or `.find()`.

Comment: @VLAZ, this was informative and will be useful going forward, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesn't returns any value.

Returning `item` from `forEach` won't make it the return value of the `find_parent` function. You need to save the value you want to return in a local variable and return that local variable from `find_parent` function.

```
function find_parent(clicked_item)
{
   let val;   // variable to hold the item that should be returned

    filter_have_children.forEach( function(item){
        var look_here = filter_children[item];
        if ( look_here.indexOf(clicked_item) != "-1" ) 
        {
            console.log("FOUND PARENT FOR: "+clicked_item+" IT IS ITEM: "+item+" TYPE: "+typeof item);
            val = item;     // save item in local variable
        }
    });

   return val;     // return the local variable containing the item
}
```

Comment: I started here because this was the easiest to implement for testing. This resolves my issue and correctly returns the item needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` is returning a value from the `forEach` callback (that return value is ignored). Your `find_parent` function doesn't ever return anything, which is why calling it results in `undefined`.

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method is what you'd want in this case:

```
function find_parent(clicked_item)
{
    return filter_have_children.find( function(item){
//  ^^^^^^                      ^^^^
        var look_here = filter_children[item];
        return look_here.indexOf(clicked_item) != -1; // <= Note -1 should be a number, not a string.
    });
}
```

Your `find` callback should return a truthy value for the item you want to find, or a falsy value for any other item. It gets called for each element in the array in order, stopping the first time your callback returns a truthy value. `find`'s result is the item that your callback said was the right one, or `undefined` if your callback never returns a truthy value.

Comment: You probably meant `-1` instead of using a string.

Comment: Or I guess maybe it doesm't matter with `!=`. I forget.

Comment: @slappy - That's the OP's code, but you're quite right, it should be `-1`.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this as the code is much cleaner.